# Knowband marketplace is not working properly on my Prestashop Store

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I have installed knowband marketplace module on prestashop 1.7 but its not working properly. I am unable to add seller from front as well as back office. When I click on any module button I am getting below mentioned error :-

**Undefined Index :- `id_kb_mp_seller`**

**Logs :-**

WARNING
12:10:26
translation Translation not found.
CRITICAL
12:10:26
php Uncaught Notice: Undefined index: id_kb_mp_seller
INFO
12:10:26
php User Deprecated: Implementing "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\DataCollectorInterface" without the "reset()" method is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and will be unsupported in 4.0 for class "Csa\Bundle\GuzzleBundle\DataCollector\GuzzleCollector".
CRITICAL
12:10:26
request Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice: Undefined index: id_kb_mp_seller" at /home/u785114660/domains/onebazaar.in/public_html/src/Adapter/Routing/LegacyHelperLinkBuilder.php line 74
WARNING
12:10:26
translation Translation not found.
DEBUG
12:10:26
php Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for /home/u785114660/domains/onebazaar.in/public_html/modules/kbmarketplace/views/js/admin/kb-marketplace-customer.js
INFO
12:10:26
php User Deprecated: AdminMarketing is a deprecated tab since version 1.7.0 and "Default" will be removed in 1.7.1.. Upgrade module using the docs: http://build.prestashop.com/news/how-we-reorganized-main-menu-prestashop-1.7/.
DEBUG
12:10:26
php Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for /home/u785114660/domains/onebazaar.in/public_html/1fknrvtft56ugkia/themes/default/css/theme.css

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the module uses some deprecated methods.

The main reason for this may be that the version of the module is not compatible with the PrestaShop version.

Ask the module developers for the new version of the module, or try the module with an older version of PrestaShop.